# Kafka printing only the producer's logger and not the consumer's

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Any idea what i might be doing wrong?
Here are the classes i'm using:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    public NewTopic javaTopic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("java").build();
    }

}
```

```
@Service
public class KafkaProducer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaProducer.class);

    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    public KafkaProducer(KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        LOGGER.info(String.format("Message sent %s", message));
        kafkaTemplate.send("java", message);
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class KafkaConsumer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaConsumer.class);

    @KafkaListener(topics = "java", groupId = "myGroup")
    public void consume(String message) {
        try {
            LOGGER.info(String.format("Message received -> %s", message));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error while processing message", e);
        }
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/kafka", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class KafkaController {

    private KafkaProducer kafkaProducer;

    public KafkaController(KafkaProducer kafkaProducer) {
        this.kafkaProducer = kafkaProducer;
    }

    @GetMapping("/publish")
    public ResponseEntity<String> publish(@RequestParam("message") String message) {
        kafkaProducer.sendMessage(message);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Message sent to the topic");
    }
}
```

When I make the request to my /GET, I only get the message in the console

```
2023-09-02T22:24:45.679-03:00 INFO 17424 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.bruno.musicrank.kafka.KafkaProducer : Message sent teste
```

Also if I use the command to see the consumer's logger, I can normally see the values that I send on my endpoint

```
kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic java --partition 0 --from-beginning
```

And here's my application.yml

```
kafka:
  bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
  consumer:
    group-id: myGroup
    auto-offset-reset: earliest
    key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
  producer:
    key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to flush the template producer.

You should've logged after a flush. Otherwise, you've only "sent" to an in memory buffer, which the consumer cannot access, since that data isn't actually in the broker yet